# Required help in make file

Tags: c, linux, makefile

i just want to implement below statement

```
"if bin folder is not available in current directory then make new bin folder & 
if bin folder is available then its do nothing"
```

can anybody give me any idea how can i do this?

EDIT : 
i dont want any error like

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `./bin `./bin': File exists
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
-mkdir ./bin
```

If `./bin` already exists then `mkdir` will fail silently, otherwise it will create the directory.

Comment: mkdir: cannot create directory `./bin': File exists
i dont want this error

Comment: @Mr.32: Note the `-` in the beginning of the line, it is important.

Answer (score 2):

Use a rule like this:

```
bin:
        mkdir bin
```

Then instead of writing `mkdir bin` as part of other rules, make them depend on the `bin` rule. The `bin` rule will only be executed if `bin` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement you can use the rule as follows:

```
bindir:
       if [ ! -d bin ];then \
           mkdir bin;  \
       fi
```

Please note that if statement checks for existence of directory named bin in the current directory where makefile resides, if directory named bin does not exist then it will create it, if it exists it does nothing, but if there is a regular file (not a directory) with the name bin exists then this rule will fail.
Suggest you to use a variable say BINDIR to store the value of your "bin" directory as that is the general norm followed, it is good for maintenance of makefile.

```
BINDIR:=bin
bindir:
       if [ ! -d $(BINDIR) ];then \
           mkdir $(BINDIR);  \
       fi
```